# How to use a pointer to a generic template class to access a member function that depends on the template parameter type

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to have a pointer to a generic template class and call a function whose return value depends on the template parameter? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class Node{...}

template < typename Type > class NumberNode : public Node
{
    public:
        NumberNode( Type value ) : _value( value ) { }

        Type getValue() { return _value; }

    private:
        Type _value;
}

void foo( int x )    { /* do something */ }
void foo( float x )  { /* do something else */ }

void main(...)
{
    std::vector< Node* > nodes;

    nodes.push_back( new NumberNode< int >( 1 ) );
    nodes.push_back( new NumberNode< float >( 1.f ) );

    for( Node* ptr_node : nodes )
    {
        foo( static_cast< NumberNode* >( ptr_node )->getValue() );
    }
}
```

I can't do this because the `static_cast( Derived* )` should know the full template type, which varies. I can't have `Base` be a template type either, for other classes also derive from it. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Can you just make the function templated, so you can specialize for the types you want?

Comment: @Ben I don't think so. The function should do completely different things dependent on the type, so it would need to branch dependent on the template parameter, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: dynamic_cast is for polymorphism. I don't think I understand what you try to achieve, so it may or may not help you.

Comment: Here are my thoughts -- if you want to have a generic "get_value()" member function that you access from a pointer to the base, you could make it virtual and then override it in each of the derived instances. But then, it has to return a single fixed type for each version. So I think you are running up against an inherent limitation of C++, when you expose an API say via a base class, each function MUST have a known-at-compile-time type. My advice is, if you want to do compile-time polymorphism then do that and skip the base class. If you must have a base class then rethink approach.

Comment: In C++ we have *class templates*, not "template classes". Class templates are not classes. `NumberNode` is a class template. `NumberNode<int>` is a class. `NumberNode<float>` is a completely different class. There is no such thing as `NumberNode*` because `NumberNode` is not a class.

Comment: Also, the standard prototype for `main` is `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`.

Comment: @ n.m. I've heard template class used to denote specific instantiations of class template.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes, sometimes. I think it's a bit of a sloppy language. The standard mentions a "template class" once, probably by mistake. There are several mentions of "non-template class".

Answer (score 2):

This is the right thing to do:

```
class Node 
{
 public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Your loop becomes

```
for( Node* ptr_node : nodes )
{
    ptr_node->foo();
}
```

`foo` can be implemented in `NumberNode` like this:

```
template <typename Type> 
void NumberNode::foo() 
{
  ::foo(_value);
}
```

Perhaps `getValue()` is no longer needed with this design and you can get rid of it. It's a good thing. Getters are manifestations of a weak design. Objects should *do* stuff, not *have* stuff.

If you don't want to have `foo` in `Node` for some reason (perhaps you have too many functions like `foo` and don't want to pollute the interface), the alternative approach is to implement the *[VISITOR pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)* for `Node`. However Visitor has its own downsides, so I would only recommend using it as a last resort in this case.